# I have purchased a domain name from go daddy , i need to host this domain on my local computer , I have tomcat 7 running on it

Tags: tomcat, dns, tomcat7, hosting

I have tried editing the host tag in server.XML , but it didn't work out.

can I do this? I don't want to host it on godaddy.com. 
Can I host it on my local computer, so that everyone can access the domain from anywhere?
If yes, where exactly I need to change the configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set up your DNS Record to point to your home internet connection
   (Most home connections change their IP address daily or weekly, so you might need to setup an automatic update mechanism here)
2. Configure your home router and firewall to forward incoming packets on ports 80 and 443 to your local computer